# Automatic trailing Slash

Tags: .htaccess

Hi Friends I am adding trailing slash and remove the extension at end of the url by following ht access conditions it was working fine my problem is if i am manually type the url without trailing slash it will not add trailing slash automatically for example if i am typing the following url

```
www.example.com/project/product
```

it will not add trailng slash automatically
my ht access condition is

```
Options -Indexes
Options +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
RewriteEngine on

# Forces a trailing slash to be added
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$
RewriteRule (.*)$ /$1/ [R=301,L]

# disable directory browsing
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.+?\ [^?]+\.php[?\ ]
RewriteRule \.php$ - [F]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.+?\ [^?]+\.html[?\ ]
RewriteRule \.html$ - [F]

ErrorDocument 403 http://www.example.com/
ErrorDocument 404 http://www.example.com/
```

Please give me your guidance to add automatic trailing slash if entering manual url

Answer (score 0):

This is because you're relying on multiviews, which is handled by a different module. This module processes the request **before** mod_rewrite does, which means your rules will never get processed. In order to do this, you'll need to turn off multiviews and handle the mapping yourself:

```
Options -Indexes
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on

# Forces a trailing slash to be added
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$
RewriteRule (.*)$ /$1/ [R=301,L]

# Handle the php mapping
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRUle ^(.*?)/?$ /$1.php [L]

# Handle the html mapping
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.html -f
RewriteRUle ^(.*?)/?$ /$1.html [L]

# disable directory browsing
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.+?\ [^?]+\.php[?\ ]
RewriteRule \.php$ - [F]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.+?\ [^?]+\.html[?\ ]
RewriteRule \.html$ - [F]

ErrorDocument 403 http://www.example.com/
ErrorDocument 404 http://www.example.com/
```

Comment: if I am disable the multiviews the same page appear three times within a page and other links not working

Comment: @rmrps That's probably because the trailing slash changes your relative URL base, and all your links are relative. Change you links to absolute URLs or add a base to your page header: `<base href="/" />`